# console.log returning undefined on post request

Tags: javascript, html, angular

the function returns a json, but when I give a console.log(this.metodo) the console returns with undefined, the function is in the ngOnit of the application, I don't know what I could be doing wrong, in the code I tried with the promise and with subscribe

```
  public metodo:any;



ngOnInit(): void {
/*     
 this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).toPromise().then(res=> 
{JSON.stringify(console.log(res))})
*/
 this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).subscribe((res) => {
  this.metodo = res;
  console.log(this.metodo);
});
}
```

The service

```
getTransporteMetodo(empId){
return this.http.post(environment.API_URL + 'transporte/getAll', { empId });
 }
```

The json

```
[
 {
"id": 1,
"emp_id": 1,
"nome": "Retirada na Loja",
"tipo": "RETIRA",
"subtipo": null,
"latLng": [-25.45264, -49.26653],
"vFreteMin": 0,
"vFreteGratis": null,
"periodos": [
  {
    "id": 8,
    "transporte_id": 1,
    "ativo": 1,
    "periodo": "Comercial (das 8h \u00e0s 19h)",
    "corte": "17:00",
    "data": null,
    "week": []
  }
]
 },
]
```

Comment: Can you check if res is not undefined too? Try console.log(res) and let me know

Comment: On      this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).toPromise().then(res=> {JSON.stringify(console.log(res))})
 res returns undefined

Comment: /* this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).subscribe((res) => {
      this.metodo = res;
      console.log(res);
}); */
with subscribe it doesn't return anything, I don't know what I'm doing wrong in both modes

Comment: Try this first and let me know this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});

Comment: in this code you sent it doesn't return anything on the console

Comment: it makes the getAll request, but it doesn't return anything in the console, and the request returns the normal json

Comment: I think the problem is with your getTransporteMetodo(empId) in your service. Try this getTransporteMetodo(empId): Observable<any>{
return this.http.post<any>(environment.API_URL + 'transporte/getAll', { empId });
 }

Comment: This code returned some errors when placed in ngOnit, would this be a function I would have to call in ngOnit ?

Comment: Just a guess, in the request you have `emp.id` - should that be `emp_id` like the response?

Comment: What value does this.storeS.layout.emp.id have? What happens if it is undefined? Would you mind posting the API too?

Comment: @lafleur 
it returns the id of the company the person is in, for example
empId: 3

Comment: @James Yes the payload empId is the same as the response emp_id

Comment: But you don't have `empId` in the payload, you have `emp.id`.

Comment: @james The payload  {"empId":4}
The response [{"id":9,"emp_id":4,"nome":"Frota Pr\u00f3pria","tipo":"FROTA","subtipo":null,"latLng":[-25.43635,-49.31626],"vFreteMin":0,"vFreteGratis":80,"periodos":[{"id":10,"transporte_id":9,"ativo":1,"periodo":"(Comercial das 9h \u00e0s 19h)","corte":"17:00","data":null,"week":[]}]},{"id":10,"emp_id":4,"nome":"Retirada na loja","tipo":"RETIRA","subtipo":null,"latLng":[-25.43394,-49.31603],"vFreteMin":0,"vFreteGratis":null,"periodos":[]}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing this in your service.ts file

```
getTransporteMetodo(empId): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post<any>(environment.API_URL + 'transporte/getAll', { empId 
   });
 }
```

You'll need this import in your service

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

After that check if in your console still appears undefined.
Let me know it worked for you

Comment: still returned as undefined, using the code
this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).toPromise().then(res =>{console.log(res)});

Comment: with this it doesn't even return indefinitely in the system
        this.cartS.getTransporteMetodo(this.storeS.layout.emp.id).subscribe((res) => { console.log(res); });